# How to share the environmental variables between windows and linux(Ubuntu)

Tags: windows, linux

I have windows 7 and ubuntu installed as dual boot. Till now i was working on Windows and have defined my user environmental variables. How can i import or use those defined in windows to ubuntu?

Comment: why do you want to do that? Maybe we can help better.
Also I think this question should be better post in serverfault site instead of stackoverflow...

Comment: Do you really think I shouldn't post this in StackOVerFlow? My whole worspace is in windows and have many user defined variables. All I wanted is to convert the same into linux equivalent env variables which makes my work simpler and so that i can share the same with others and reduce their effort of redoing this?

Comment: In general if you choose correct **StackExchange** site for your question you will get better feedback. Anyway I have answered to it the best I knew :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this? If you explain why maybe there is a better option. It looks pretty complicated.

Anyway, assuming you need it, I think this might work:

- You will have to create a disk unit that is mounted in both windows and linux by default.
- You create then a text file containing variables you want to set up.
- In windows boot you add a program (batch file, powershell) that somehow read these environment text file and loads variables
- Do the same in linux with a a bash script in boot or similar.